# Put file names into text

Tags: linux, bash, text, text-processing

I have at least 40 files (20 in `xml.` format and 20 in `safe.` format).
As example some of this:

```
iw1-20150612.SAFE.safe
iw2-20150714.SAFE.safe
iw1-20150612.xml
iw2-20150714.xml
```

I want to put this **file names** in a txt file in a certain place of text via terminal in Linux (or text is added during this process)

The text can be any as example:

```
anytext iw1-20150612.SAFE.safe
anytext2 iw1-20150612.xml anytext2  iw1-20150612.xml
anytext Iw2-20150714.SAFE.safe
anytext2 iw2-20150714.xml anytext2  iw2-20150714.xml
```

**Example that I need here**:

```
awk 'NR>1 {print $0}' < ../og/iw1-20150612.SAFE.safe > tmp_file
cat ../og/iw1-20150612.xml tmp_file ../og/m.xml > ./iw1-20150612.xml
awk 'NR>1 {print $0}' < ../og/iw2-20150714.SAFE.safe > tmp_file
cat ../og/iw2-20150714.xml tmp_file ../og/m.xml > ./iw2-20150714.xml
#and etc
```

It's also important to keep sorting by file name as in the folder.
My attempt:

```
find /any/directory/ -type f -printf "%f\n" >> data.txt
```

But I don't know how to 'choose a place' to insert text.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That's better? I hope now become clear

Comment: @user2899758: It is no where clear on what is that you are trying to do? BTW what is wrong with your attempts?

Comment: I add my unsuccessful attempt and edit Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple bash for loop to loop over the filenames. As long as each `safe` file has a corresponding `xml` file, you can

- loop over the `safe` files,
- get the base filename  without extension
- and create the `xml` filename and the texts from there

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

OUTFILE=textfile
EXTENSION=.SAFE.safe

# rm -rf "$OUTFILE" # uncomment if required
for f in *${EXTENSION}
do
    # f i a .. safe file we remove the extension 
    base=${f%%$EXTENSION}
    echo -e "anytext $f\nanytext2 ${base}.xml anytext2 ${base}.xml" >> "$OUTFILE"
done
```

Set `OUTFILE` as required, uncomment the `rm` if required.

**Update using awk**

If you have many files and the bash for loop is to slow due to frequent writes to `$OUTFILE`, here is a more shell-style version of the same idea:

- we pipe the `SAVE.safe` filenames into awk,
- use the dot as field separator (thus `$1` is the basename, `$0` the original filename)
- and create the desired text with `printf`:

  ```
  ls -1 *.SAFE.safe | awk -F. '{printf("anytext %s\nanytext2 %s.xml anytext2\n",$0,$1)}'
  ```

Comment: Very cool thanks, worked! However, for interest, and if the names are different for different file formats? I was able to do this for only one file format. `for a in $(cd any/directory; ls *xml)
do 
   echo "anytext$a anytext$a" >> data.txt
done`

Comment: If different extensions need different output and you want to keep the sequence, you need `if statements` on the extension. The documentation on bash or awk has all the details.